# Why isn't this function to calculate the average of an integer list not working?

Tags: haskell, integer, average

I'm trying to make a function which adds up all the numbers from a given list and then divides it by 6.

```
average :: [Integer] -> Integer
average m = (sum m) quot 6
```

But this is the error message I'm receiving:

```
Couldn't match type `Integer'                                                                                
              with `(a0 -> a0 -> a0) -> a1 -> Integer'                                                       
Expected type: [(a0 -> a0 -> a0) -> a1 -> Integer]                                                           
  Actual type: [Integer]                                                                                     
In the first argument of `sum', namely `m'                                                                   
In the expression: (sum m) quot 6
```

Comment: `(sum m) quot 6` means "take `sum` and apply it to `m`, then take the resulting function and apply it to `quot`, and then take the resulting function and apply it to `6`". It is the same as `sum m quot 6`. However, `sum m` does not return a function, so a type error is raised.

Answer (score 5):

You need backticks around `quot`, or write it first

```
sum m `quot` 6
quot (sum m) 6
```

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell we write the function name before the arguments. For *quot* you write:

```
quot 17 2
```

So in your case:

```
quot (sum m) 6
```

Haskell has some sytactic sugar that allows you to write functions in so called *infix* notation. This is what user mb14 refers to.